# Why are my raster mean and standard deviation -1?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, statistics, python-2.7

I have a set of about 25 rasters whose descriptive statistics I have been examining. The data in the rasters were calculated in Python and the rasters were created using Python-GDAL.

In all but one raster, the mean, std. dev., minimum and maximum seem correct. In one raster, however, the minimum and maximum  values are correct (4.842 and 9.458 respectively) but the mean and standard deviation are `-1` if I take a look in ArcCatalog and `-1.#IND` in QGIS.

I opened the raster in Python via GDAL and calculated the minimum and maximum using `data[data>band.GetNoDataValue()].min()` and `data[data>band.GetNoDataValue()].max()` respectively, and the values these functions returned were correct (as above). But the mean value via `data[data>band.GetNoDataValue()].mean()` was 2.905, which is clearly nonsense as this value does not occur within the minimum and maximum value limits for this raster. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: Is there a .aux.xml file associated with the file?  If so delete it and run gdalinfo -stats again.  What file format?